# Reputation lost without any trace?

Tags: support, feature-request, reputation, reputation-history

I just recognized that I lost a lot of reputation. I am not sure how much but a significant amount at least 300.

I reached 30k reputation I posted this screenshot [in January](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/19132?m=35392140#35392140):
[image: 30k rep]

I see in my reputation history only grow no lost why am I back to 29.999?

The [cached google result](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:vqz6skxcwIoJ:stackoverflow.com/users/995926/rekire%20&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=firefox-b) of my profile says that I had recently a reputation of 30.307

**Feature request:**
If this is really a result of a documentation based reputation recalculation I would like to have in my profile at least a hint that a reputation recalculation has happend. In best case also the actual change.

Comment: This is most likely related to the current Documentation reputation recalculations going on.

Comment: Well that is a little frustrating, but explains what is going on. However I would like to have a official confirmation.

Comment: I would also suggest you check your recently deleted questions and answers to see if anything was deleted.

Comment: I checked that before: There are only positive changes.

Comment: Yes I have in the Beta time and a little afterwards.

Comment: @rekire sadly - this was docs - and like the linked dupe says - the auditing/explanation for it is non-existent. You went from 30,374->29,944 on the 22nd... *exactly* because of why/what happened in the docs recalc... don't think anyone can tell you...

Comment: Just out of interested do I have any reputation from docs now? As far I remember most of the reputation came from a migrated posting which was almost invisible in the documentation history. So I have here possible an edge case.

Comment: @JonClements did I get any reputation from e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1552/logging-and-using-logcat#t=201702242037377156877 ? I wrote that.